# how can i redirect from void method to a view?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void verifyAccount(string id)
    {
        if (clientDB.verifyAccount(id)!="")
        {


           // Redirect("index");//redirect to index view

        }
        else
        {
            //redirect to error view
        }

    }
```

i try to use Redirect("Index"); but it does not work, Is it impossible to redirect to view from a void method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect from a method that returns void. In order to redirect, you must return an `ActionResult`, and since this method returns *nothing*, you obviously cannot achieve that.

Setting the return type of an action to `void` is just a simplistic way of saying it returns a response with a 200 status code and no response body. If that's not actually the case, as it isn't here, then you should not have a return type of `void`. Here, the only response possible is a redirect, so your action should have a return type of either `ActionResult` or `RedirectResult`. It's generally better to just use `ActionResult` for everything though, as it's the base class for all other types of results. You can even achieve the same thing as if you used `void` by doing `return new EmptyResult();` or simply `return null;`.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. I have implemented and override of void HandleUnnknownAction  in one of my controllers. 

It gets called if an action on the page cannot be found. Great. But if one is not found I want to redirect them to another view. 

HandleUnknownAction cannot return ActionResult.  Still looking for a solution here .

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can with HandleUnknownAction

```
RedirectToAction("Index").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
```

Comment: A workaround: Use the snippet from @FPasaoglu, and take to an IActionResult that's make the redirect!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it impossible to redirect to view from a void method?

Yes. Your action should return an `ActionResult` type and return the redirect (or view).

Comment: is it possible to call `ActionResult` method from void method? if yes, then how

Answer (score 0):

its not right but you can use Response.Redirect("~/Home/Login");

but in some case it can happedn that antiforgerytokenm will throw exception...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return redirect from a void action method but instead you can use this way to verify before a controller excution

```
//base controller
 public class VerifyAcountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _Context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUsers> _UserManager;
        public VerifyAcountController(IUnitOfWork Context, UserManager<ApplicationUsers> UserManager)
        {
            _Context = Context;
            _UserManager = UserManager;
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
            //base Codes Here
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new { action = "Login", controller = "UserAcount" });       
            }
        }
    }
```

```
//main controller
 public class PaymentController : VerifyAcountController
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _Context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUsers> _UserManager;
        public PaymentController(UserManager<ApplicationUsers> UserManager,IUnitOfWork context) : base(context, UserManager)
        {
            _Context = context;
            _UserManager = UserManager;
        }
         public IActionResult ShopCart()
        {
            GetUser();
            var basket = GetBasket();          
            return View(basket);
        }
}
```