# Redirect to a Controller from class method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

please I have a void method in a class and i want from this method to redirect to an action in a controller, i try to use `RedirectToAction` but I didn't saw it in the Intellisense, please do you have any idea about how can I redirect from this void method into a Controller Action.

I work on ASP.NET MVC Application

massive thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i redirect from void method to a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739282/how-can-i-redirect-from-void-method-to-a-view)

Comment: @GSerg close, but that question is about a void in a controller.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you bro all respect you are a good man massive thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You could, using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` or something like that, but **don't**, because then you bypass the entire MVC pipeline.

A non-controller class doesn't (or at least shouldn't) know that it's being used in an ASP.NET MVC context. You call a method on a class to let that method perform a particular task.

If a certain result of that task, again, in an MVC context, should result in your web application redirecting the user to another action, then do so in your controller.

So, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var result = someOtherClass.Bar();

    if (result.WhatEver)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(...);
    }

    return View(...);
}
```

And yes, this means that `Bar()` probably shouldn't be `void`, but return something meaningful.

An you generally also don't want classes you call from controllers return an `ActionResult`-derived result.

Comment: but please i don't want to return a view, i just want to do some operations without returning view

Comment: @ADSMB returning a view is an optional thing to do. Nowhere does it state that you have to follow through the full cycle of the Model-View-Controller eco-system. And for Web API's - you shouldn't. You can simply return a status response.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet in your void:

```
RedirectToAction("SomeAction").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
```

So, use IActionResult to performance the redirect

```
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    RedirectToAction("SomePlace", "SomeController");
}
```